# Open a podcast via URL in a browser and enforce autoplay

Tags: audio, browser, url, podcasts

Is there a way to open a podcast (via its URL) in a browser (say: Firefox) and, e.g. by adding something to the URL, force it to play right away when the podcast gets called?

For example use this URL

```
https://tasteofharmony.podigee.io/11-colombia-spain-ireland
```

(which is indeed one of the actual podcast episodes I want to play that way).

I imagine something like adding

```
&autoplay=1
```

to the URL, and thus make the podcast play right way. However, this trick (which I took from Youtube) does not work as simply as I hoped.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: As squillman answered, this isn't really possible. But for this specific website/player, when you click Share there is a download button that gives you a direct link to the audio, which opens in a web browser and plays (autoplays, is the browser autoplays audio files.)

Comment: Ah, okay, yes, that could open a work-around...

Comment: @YisroelTech - Your above hint does indeed help a lot. I can copy this address from the player, store it, and call the podcast with it so that it plays right away. That's actually what I needed (although with the little additional work of storing yet another address; but that's okay).

Answer (score 3):

Something like `&autoplay=1` is a parameter to the web site that you are loading.  YouTube is specifically written to recognize that parameter; it's not a global feature to every site.  If the site doesn't know what that is, adding it to the URL isn't going to do anything.  If the podcast has an autoplay feature then there will be a way, but this will be specific to each site and, if not, you'll have to resort to a browser extension or something that can recognize media within the page and auto-start it.

Comment: What I am actually doing is programming a little Python thingy to open a bunch of different podcasts. Opening the web pages (for each podcast) does work already, but getting the audios started is the issue here. I had something similar working for Youtube videos already (as you probably could alreacy conclude from my initial question).  If there is a way to "press the play button" via Python, that would also help...

Comment: For any automation solution you're either going to have to parse the page HTML or use browser automation (like Selenium) to find the button and execute it's click event.  The problem in that is it will generally be different on every different site you load.  It's likely the only commonalities you'll run into is if you get multlple podcasts hosed on the same platform.

Answer (score 0):

[Autoplay policy in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)
is quite complicated, but you can always force autoplay by running
the Chrome command-line as follows:

```
chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required URL
```

For Firefox, you need to follow the article
[Allow or block media autoplay in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay).

- You may set a global option for all websites in
  *Settings > Privacy & Security > Autoplay > Settings*
- For a specific site, you may in its Site Information, set Autoplay
  under "Permissions".

Comment: All this is for autoplay on things that try to autoplay, the question is about making something autoplay when the website itself doesn't try to auto play it

Comment: @YisroelTech: What's the difference between adding a parameter to the URL or rather to the browser call (Chrome)? Or to the website Site Information (Firefox)? Rather than explain why it can't be done like in the other answer, I try to explain what *can* easily be done, which is useful and doesn't merit a downvote.

Comment: Note that in the poster's example, the URL is not to the video, but to a page that invokes the video. There's no autoplay involved here, but rather auto-click, which is totally different.

Comment: So the OP's question is about auto-click, or (erroneously thinking it's possible) somehow autoplay the video on that page by adding a parameter to the URL (a YouTube link is also not "the video" but can still be autoplayed with a URL parameter.) So your answer is irrelevant to his question.

Comment: @YisroelTech: No, my answer is relevant to his question, it's his example that's irrelevant.

Comment: ‍♂️. His URL is the URL he's trying to do what he is trying to do. The answer might be that he can't do it with that URL (as squillman correctly answered), but you can't give the OP a solution for some other website/system/platform he is not asking about... ("How can do so-and-so on my Mac?" "On your Android, you can do it by doing so-and-so"....)

Comment: @YisroelTech: Read the title of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of Yisroel Tech to my original question I found a solution - actually not to the question as it was asked, but anyway to the underlying problem I tried to solve.

Here is the solution in my own words:

On the web page

```
https://tasteofharmony.podigee.io/11-colombia-spain-ireland
```

there is an integrated player, and this player offers a link for --> Share --> Download. The link is (in this case):

```
https://audio.podigee-cdn.net/1150815-m-88b8a064a50c04a92a28687ff7271261.mp3?source=webplayer-download
```

In a standard setup (ordinary browser) this link causes the record to play immediately.

Despite the original problem not being solved (and probably impossible to be solved the way I asked for), for my specific use-case this is good enough. I can use these links (addresses) to call the podcasts and play them right away.